Trying to understand $\widetilde{W_\alpha}$ during the universe construction in simplicial sets?
I am reading https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2851 'The Simplicial Model of Univalent Foundations (after Voevodsky)' and I have problems to understand construction of $\widetilde{W_\alpha}$ that is being made on p.18 (Arxiv latest, v5) immediately after 'Notation 2.1.6' - there is paragraph from 5 lines which contains the following confusions:

"Simplicial set $\widetilde{W_\alpha} \to W_\alpha$":
Why is the phrase "simplicial set" followed by the morphism $\widetilde{W_\alpha} \to W_\alpha$? Can a morphism itself be a simplicial set, or is there some trick, some folklore? Is it correct to think that the morphism $\widetilde{W_\alpha} \to W_\alpha$ represents some simplicial set, or is there another interpretation?

"n-simplices of $\widetilde{W_\alpha}$ are classes of pairs $(f : Y \to \Delta[n], s \in f^{-1}(1[n]))$":
Why are the $n$-simplices of $\widetilde{W_\alpha}$ described as classes of pairs? Well- there can be (almost?) any set that can be assigned to [n] for some simplicial set and so - this class of pairs can be such set. But the paper says, that this set is "classes of pairs"? So - is it set of classes and what is varying inside each class (to allow that class can contain multiple pairs generally) and what is varying among classes (allow the existence of set of classes)?

"$\lceil f \rceil \in W_\alpha$" and n-simplices vs morphisms:
In the sentence, they refer to $\lceil f \rceil \in W_\alpha$ as an $n$-simplex. However, in the previous paragraph, they define $\lceil f \rceil$ as a map from some simplicial set $X$ to $W_\alpha$. Why do they describe this as an $n$-simplex and not just a morphism? Can you explain why this morphism is considered an $n$-simplex in this context?


I am trying to understand the construction of universes and I am starting from this paper and I have https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07004 'All (∞,1)-toposes have strict univalent universes' in the store for the more general case. I am aware of the summary by Emily Rhiel https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.06937 'On the ∞-topos semantics of homotopy type theory', but it does not help me with this confusing paragraph. Maybe there is good textbook or another review article or some more historical articles, which can help me to understand this construction of universes?


This looks like an abuse of language to say "a simplicial set $\widetilde{W_\alpha}$ equipped with a canonical projection $\widetilde{W_\alpha} \to W_\alpha$".
I'm not sure I understand the question, but here we are computing the simplicial set $\widetilde{W_\alpha}$ (up to canonical isomorphism) using the previous lemmas. We defined $\widetilde{W_\alpha}$ as the total space of the element of $\mathbf{W}_\alpha(W_\alpha)$ corresponding to $\mathrm{id} : \mathrm{Hom}(W_\alpha, W_\alpha)$; unfolding the Yoneda-coYoneda machinery in lemma 2.1.5, we find that $\widetilde{W_\alpha}$ is computed using the "surjectivity" part of lemma 2.1.4, with $$\mathcal{J} = \int W_\alpha$$ $$F(n, [f : Y \to \Delta[n]]) = \Delta[n]$$ $$X = W_\alpha$$ $$[f_{(n, [g])}] = [g]$$ Thus, an $n$-simplex of the total space $\widetilde{W_\alpha}$ is a pair of an $n$-simplex of $W_\alpha$ (that is, an isomorphism class $[f : Y \to \Delta[n]]$) and an element of the fibre over $[f]$, which is $f^{-1}(1_{[n]})$.
By the Yoneda lemma, $n$-simplices of $W_\alpha$ are in bijection with maps $\Delta[n] \to W_\alpha$, hence of the form $\lceil f \rceil$ for some $f : Y \to \Delta[n]$. We are using the bijection implicitly here.

